# Create a score card report based on match results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, union

Here's my sample input of match results from a tournament and the result column indicates whether team 1 or team 2 won the game (0 stands for a draw).

```
score table -
-----------------
t1   t2   result
-----------------
us   aus    1
aus  sa     2
sa   us     0
us   nz     1

Desired output -
---------------------------------
team    played  won lost    draw
---------------------------------
aus     2       0     2     0
us      3       2     0     1
nz      1       0     1     0
sa      2       1     0     1
```

Here's my solution that I came up with, but Is it possible to solve it without using a UNION operator?

```
select 
  t1 as team,
  count(1) as played,
  sum(case when result=1 then 1 else 0 end) as won,
  sum(case when result=2 then 1 else 0 end) as lost,
  sum(case when result=0 then 1 else 0 end) as draw
from 
(select
   t1, 
   t2, 
   result
 from score
 union
select
   t2, 
   t1, 
   case when result=1 then 2
        when result=2 then 1
        else 0 end as result
 from score
) t
group by t.t1
```

Comment: Do you understand the often significant difference between UNION and UNION ALL?

Comment: @SMor I know that UNION removes the duplicate records from the result set, returning only distinct records, whereas UNION ALL returns all the records. UNION ALL is faster than UNION, since it does not have to scan the results again to removes the duplicate records. Is there something else that I should be knowing above, please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could UNPIVOT your data via a `CROSS APPLY` and then perform the aggregation on the results

**Example**

```
Select  Team
       ,played = count(1)
       ,won    = sum(case when Val=1 then 1 else 0 end)
       ,lost   = sum(case when Val=2 then 1 else 0 end)
       ,draw   = sum(case when Val=0 then 1 else 0 end)
From  score A
Cross Apply ( values (T1,Result )
                    ,(T2,case when result=1 then 2 when result=2 then 1 else 0 end)
           ) B(Team,Val)
 Group By Team
```

**Results**

```
team    played  won lost    draw
aus     2       0   2       0
nz      1       0   1       0
sa      2       1   0       1
us      3       2   0       1
```